# How do I preg replace the following at linux command line

Tags: php, html, linux

How do I preg replace the following at linux command line

```
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="../../pear.png" />
```

I want to preg replace away the ../../ to make it become

```
<link rel="pear-icon" sizes="100" href="pear.png" />
```

Because there a lot of ../../ in my link, how do i mass preg replace and recursive on all file that contain this ../../

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/"\.\.\/\.\.\/pear\.png/"pear\.png/g'
```

Try it first on 1 file though... didnt test this myself

Comment: I got a lot files that contain ../../ , its not only pear, is there a more uninversal method

Comment: @RichardBernards you should swap the order of sed args, your example does exactly opposite of OPs question.

Comment: @Baokychen you just need to remove both `pear\.png`

Comment: @baldrs No!!!! Than it's replacing every occurrence of `"../../` with `"` which is not the same

Comment: @RichardBernards but he wants to get rid of `../../`

Comment: @baldrs I know, but we do not know the contents of the files he is trying this on. If in a file we can find the following string: `$path = $rootDir . "../../../../asdf";`, this could potentially break this code